# mysql query from log table

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `filelog` (
  `date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `file` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

action could have values 'upload' and 'delete'

I have a list view where the files that are uploaded are displayed for deletion. The problem is that the same file could be deleted and again uploaded numerous times and this is a log table where all these action are inserted. So the query should display the files with action 'upload' where the most recent action 'delete' took place before the 'upload' action.

Comment: A question with no question-mark! why don't use `order by date_time desc` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your requirement is logically equivalent to

"Show the most recent entry for each given file IFF this most recent entry is an upload"

Is that correct? If so...

```
SELECT F1.*
FROM filelog F1
WHERE F1.action = 'upload' AND F1.date_time =
          SELECT max(F2.date_time)
          FROM filelog F2
          WHERE F2.file = F1.file
```

You still want it if there has NEVER been a deletion right?

Comment: If the user has re-uploaded that file twice or more, it will miss a delete action. Questionable to business logic.

Comment: can you give a counterexample where these are not equivalent?  i dont understand what the issue is

Comment: The issue could be when the user has 10 `update` actions in row, and no delete action for these. Your query will list these too.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about that. As said it's Questionable to business logic

Comment: you think we only want to list the most recent upload if it immediately follows a deletion?

Comment: business logic is an overused buzz word.  theres no business here.  whats questionable is the desired output, which im trying to ask about

Comment: Thanks. This one worked perfectly. Even in cases where there are multiple upload actions without the delete action in between.

Is there a way not to use a subquery. Also this table is going to be REALLY huge once this is in production.

Comment: no problem.  did i understand your problem correctly?  If for a given file, there are actions in this order:  UPLOAD, DELETE, UPLOAD, UPLOAD  which should the query return?  Just the final upload, or the last two?

Comment: Only the final upload. Actually there are more columns. a single file could be uploaded to several servers. So based on server host and filename if there are multiple log entries then the last one should be displayed.

Comment: There must be either a subquery or a join of some type.  I don't believe it can be done without one of these

Comment: you say the table will be huge, so be sure to index both `file` and `date_time`.  it will make INSERT/UPDATE just slightly slower, but will greatly speed up some SELECT queries.  InnoDB has only BTREE index, so there is no issue of choosing what type of index

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   filelog f 
       JOIN (SELECT FILE, 
                    max(date_time) 
             FROM   filelog 
             WHERE  ACTION = 'delete' 
             GROUP  BY FILE) d 
         ON d.FILE = f.FILE 
            AND d.date_time < f.date_time 
WHERE  ACTION = 'update'
```

This reads the most recent deletes on files in the derived table. And joins the outer table with these.

you need indexes on

- (file,date_time)

Comment: Rather than using the order by, you probably want to use `max(date_time) as date_time` in the select.